# CouchDB - Auto-increment

Tags: couchdb

In a non-replicate scenario (or one where we have one write master only), would the following work as quick way to give a doc an auto-increment id to small internal customer datbase.

On inserting a new customer query http://couhdb/mydb to get the metadata

Then add doc_count + doc_deleted_count = autoIncId

Set a property on the doc as .oldDbCompatIdThatClientIsUsedTo = auotIncId

This would mean serialize/sync the process of getting  the db metadata and writting the doc but thats not a problem given 20 customers added a day etc..

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways of doing this:

- Create a view that returns `max(id)` and just assign `max(id) + 1` to the new item (there's some chance of collision here though)
- Store another document in the database that isn't a normal record but just contains the sequence value. When you want to do a new insert fetch the current value from this doc, add one, save it back to the doc and then if none of that failed use that id for the new record

Comment: Good idea but max(id) has the possibility of reassigning the same id if a doc is ever deleted - i guess one could work around that soft deletes. The latter is what I have at the moment but it feels yucky.

Comment: Good point, I'd missed that with `max(id)`. I would likely stick with UUIDs and try to avoid the need for an incremental id

Comment: How about connections concurrency?  You will get some duplicated ids with several connections at the same time.